# Retrofit v2-beta1 Multipart issue

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I upgraded Retrofit v1.9 to v2-Beta1 but when I want to upload photo in multipart I've this issue :

```
Unable to create @Part converter for int (parameter #4)
```

This is my interface :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/photos/upload")
    Call<String> postPhoto(@Part("file") RequestBody f,
                 @Part("title") String title, @Part("resource_type") int type,
                 @Part("resource_id") long id);
```

Any ideas ?